# Pentaho 4.4 Database connectivity issue

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am getting the following in one of my transformations. I am trying to extract data from SQL server and pushing to mongodb.

```
2014/04/03 13:11:10 - EMPLOYEE TABLE Input.0 - linenr 700000
2014/04/03 13:11:49 - Database lookup.0 - linenr 700000
2014/04/03 13:12:28 - Select values.0 - linenr 700000
2014/04/03 13:14:26 - EMPLOYEE TABLE Input.0 - linenr 750000
2014/04/03 13:15:05 - Database lookup.0 - linenr 750000
2014/04/03 13:15:47 - Select values.0 - linenr 750000
2014/04/03 13:17:43 - EMPLOYEE TABLE Input.0 - linenr 800000
2014/04/03 13:18:21 - Database lookup.0 - linenr 800000
2014/04/03 13:18:59 - Select values.0 - linenr 800000
2014/04/03 13:20:55 - EMPLOYEE TABLE Input.0 - linenr 850000
2014/04/03 13:21:34 - Database lookup.0 - linenr 850000
2014/04/03 13:22:15 - Select values.0 - linenr 850000
2014/04/03 13:24:12 - EMPLOYEE TABLE Input.0 - linenr 900000
2014/04/03 13:24:51 - Database lookup.0 - linenr 900000
2014/04/03 13:25:30 - Select values.0 - linenr 900000
2014/04/03 13:27:31 - EMPLOYEE TABLE Input.0 - linenr 950000
2014/04/03 13:28:10 - Database lookup.0 - linenr 950000
2014/04/03 13:28:52 - Select values.0 - linenr 950000
2014/04/03 13:30:53 - EMPLOYEE TABLE Input.0 - linenr 1000000
2014/04/03 13:31:33 - Database lookup.0 - linenr 1000000
2014/04/03 13:32:11 - Select values.0 - linenr 1000000
2014/04/03 13:33:43 - EMPLOYEE TABLE Input.0 - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2014/04/03 13:33:43 - EMPLOYEE TABLE Input.0 - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2014/04/03 13:33:43 - EMPLOYEE TABLE Input.0 - Couldn't get row from result set
2014/04/03 13:33:43 - EMPLOYEE TABLE Input.0 - I/O Error: Connection reset
2014/04/03 13:33:43 - EMPLOYEE TABLE Input.0 - 
2014/04/03 13:33:43 - EMPLOYEE TABLE Input.0 -
```

and at the transformation level am getting the following error

I am getting

> 2014/04/03 13:33:43 - TASK COLLECTION - Invalid state, the Statement object is closed.  2014/04/03 13:33:43 - TASK COLLECTION -
>   ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by
>   buildguy) : Errors detected! 2014/04/03 13:33:43 - TASK COLLECTION -
>   ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by
>   buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
>   2014/04/03 13:33:43 - TASK COLLECTION - Error cancelling statement
>   2014/04/03 13:33:43 - TASK COLLECTION - Invalid state, the Statement
>   object is closed. 2014/04/03 13:33:43 - TASK COLLECTION - 2014/04/03
>   13:33:43 - TASK COLLECTION - at
>   org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.cancelStatement(Database.java:664)
>   2014/04/03 13:33:43 - TASK COLLECTION - at
>   org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.cancelQuery(Database.java:646)
>   2014/04/03 13:33:43 - TASK COLLECTION - at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.stopRunning(TableInput.java:303)
>   2014/04/03 13:33:43 - TASK COLLECTION - at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans.stopAll(Trans.java:1729) 2014/04/03
>   13:33:43 - TASK COLLECTION - at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.step.BaseStep.stopAll(BaseStep.java:2605)
>   2014/04/03 13:33:43 - TASK COLLECTION - at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:95) 2014/04/03
>   13:33:43 - TASK COLLECTION - at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>   2014/04/03 13:33:43 - TASK COLLECTION - Caused by:
>   java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Statement object is closed.
>   2014/04/03 13:33:43 - TASK COLLECTION - at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.checkOpen(JtdsStatement.java:220)

Now How should I proceed with this issue. I am very much new to these things. Any guidance would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Based on your timestamps, the 2nd section of errors are probably caused by your connection reset error above.

As for the connection reset error, it is probably being caused by some limit configured in pentaho or your database server. Is there anything helpful in your database logs?

If its not something obvious on the db logs... I haven't had too much experience with pentaho, can you provide the job that is failing in a text format? And just checking, how many rows are in your table?